# Magento Error while trying to order / cancel an order that has more than one item

Tags: magento

Hy

After the onepage checkout, in Magento, I received the following email error message
...
Payment transaction failed.
Reason
Mage registry key "_singleton/model/observer" already exists 
Checkout Type
onepage 
....

And on the admin page, when trying to delete this oreder, same error, again:

```
There has been an error processing your request

Mage registry key "_singleton/model/observer" already exists

Trace:
#0 /app/Mage.php(223): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /app/Mage.php(478): Mage::register('_singleton/mode...', false)
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('model/observer')
#3 /app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('cataloginventor...', Array)
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(466): Mage::dispatchEvent('cataloginventor...', Array)
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php(787): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->_afterSave()
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(319): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item->_afterSave()
#7 l/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Observer.php(809): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock->backItemQty('542', 1)
#9 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1338): Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer->cancelOrderItem(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'cancelOrderItem', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#11 /app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('sales_order_ite...', Array)
```

..and so on

This only happends to orders that have more than one item.

Any help will be appreciated, especially because the website is in production now.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me add a bit of Magento 'anatomy' to Alan's answer:

From your error log:

```
#10 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1317): `Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer), 'cancelOrderItem', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
```

class: Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer

model: cataloginventory/observer

method: cancelOrderItem

This mean what #2 should be:

```
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/observer')
```

But you have:

```
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1316): Mage::getSingleton('model/observer')
```

Why it failed:

1) when Magento try to execute Mage::getSingleton('model/observer') it call getSingleton() function from Alan's answer.

2) registry don't have '_singleton/model/observer' so it try to register it:

```
self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
```

3) it call self::getModel('model/observer', array())) for registration and this method fails because you don't have such model.

Again, you have 'model/observer' model in one of your xml configuration files, but Magento can't find physical file with this model.

What to do? 
This is occurs on 'sales_order_item_cancel' event, so try to find this string in config.xml files in third-party extension folders.

If in one of config.xml you find something like:

```
...
    <events>
   ...
    <sales_order_item_cancel>
        <observers>
            <inventory>
                <class>model/observer</class>
                <method>cancelOrderItem</method>
            </inventory>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_item_cancel>
    ...
    </events>
...
```

Just comment `<sales_order_item_cancel>` section. 
If you want to make it working, set correct value in `<class>model/observer</class>` section.

Comment: Yap.. that was it...  I had installed a "Low Qty Notification" extension that was interfering with the default process. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

That's a curious error -- my guess is you're dealing with a "core-hack"/edut (perhaps unintentionally) of your `app/Mage.php` file.

If you look at your stack trace, Magento calls

```
Mage::getSingleton('model/observer')
```

This is Magento's ways of saying "Instantiate a `model/observer` object, and make it a singleton instance", If you're not familiar with them, singletons are a "global" object that can only be instantiated once.  If you try to instantiate a singleton again you get the original instance.

If you look at the implementation of `getSingleton`

```
#File: app/Mage.php
public static function getSingleton($modelClass='', array $arguments=array())
{
    $registryKey = '_singleton/'.$modelClass;
    if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {
        self::register($registryKey, self::getModel($modelClass, $arguments));
    }
    return self::registry($registryKey);
}
```

You can see the call to `self::registry` from your stack trace that causes the error.  However, you can also see that Magento **checks to make sure the registry key doesn't exist** via the `if (!self::registry($registryKey)) {` conditional.

My guess is someone changed the definition of `getSingleton`, or `registry` or `register` in your `app/Mage.php` file.  In a sock Magento system it should not be possible to receive the exact error you've posted here.

Comment: Hello Allen. Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately this is not the solution to my problem. I've double checked the **getSingleton** method and it's all in order. I'm still out of ideas, so if you have another solution, please share. Thank you

Comment: @user2110973 I hope this doesn't come off as too dismissive, but you haven't checked that everything's in order. The code above checks to see if something in the registry before adding it to avoid your error.  Your system skips this check for reasons unknown. Figure that out and you'll solve your problem.